# Aligining Strings In WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, string, alignment

I want to print data like this:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/align-string-with-spaces/

```
 -------------------------------
 Bi1l       | Gates      |    51
 EdnA       | Parker     |   114
 JohNny     | Depp       |    44
 -------------------------------
```

I tried using the example above, `PadRight` and `PadLeft` and more calculations of length, and I always got this type of output (my output goes to a `TextBox`)

```
 -------------------------------
 Bill      | Gates      |    51
 Edna       | Parker  |   114
 Johnny       | Depp       |    44
 -------------------------------
```

For what I think, it happens because WPF doesn't give a fixed and equal block for every character, so `W` takes more space than `i`, and makes the separations look bad.

Can someone help me out with a solution?

Comment: If you want to print it to a textbox, would it be acceptable to use a monospaced font?

Comment: @Lennart any solution that would make it look like i want would be acceptable..

Comment: seems interesting because if you manually insert tab. (with Tab option enabled) it will tab correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change your font type to [Monospace font (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) like `Courier`.

According to the linked wikipedia article other possible font types are `Courier New`, `Lucida Console`, `Monaco`or `Consolas`.

Alternatively you can change your UI and display your data using some kind of grid control like the [DataGrid](http://www.wpftutorial.net/datagrid.html) control to display your data.